# Access Subsite list from root site using sharepoint hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-hosted-app, office-365-developer

I've a SharePoint Hosted App and its deployed to Root site. Using that App, I need to read items of specific list from all sub sites of that root site. My current Code:

```
var hostsuburl = "Subsite URL goes here";
    var context = new SP.ClientContext(hostsuburl);
    var oList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("ResourceDetails");
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='monthnumber'/><Value Type='Text'>" + CurrentMonth + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    context.load(collListItem, 'Include(ActualHours,AvailableHours,CostPerHour)');
    context.executeQueryAsync(function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    alert('Inside OnQuery succeeded');
    }
 , function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
      alert('Error onQuery Failed');
  });
```

But I can't get into either `onQuerySucceeded` function & `onQueryFailed` function. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I can get into subsite, but I can't read list items, My code:

```
context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appweburl);
context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostsuburl);
this.web = appContextSite.get_web();
var olist = this.web.get_lists().getByTitle('ResourceDetails');
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery(); 
camlQuery.set_viewXml("some query goes here");
this.oListCollitems = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
context.load(oListCollitems, 'Include(ActualHours,AvailableHours,CostPerHour)');
context.ExecuteQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler1), Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler1));
 function successHandler1() {
        alert('Inside Successhandler1');
     }
function errorHandler1() {
     alert('Inside Error Handler1');
     }
```

I'm still not get into either `successhandler1()` or `errorhandler1()` How to load list items and Enumerate to get all list items? Pls correct me, if i'm using wrong method.

Comment: Any console error?

Comment: @AtishDipongkor I'm getting following error 
Error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: The object is used in the context different from the one associated with the object.
Error.create()
 msajaxbundle.js:1
Error.invalidOperation()
 msajaxbundle.js:1.......

Comment: Can you run your code inside `SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
// here goes your code
});`

Comment: @AtishDipongkor I tried, Now I'm in OnQueryFailed function.

Comment: You don't need to load the web unless you're getting web properties.  If you just need list items, then remove the `context.load(this.web);`, and the `context.executeQueryAsync()` after it.  Go straight to getting the list items.

Comment: @wjervis I've removed it (see my updated code above). But I'm still not able to get list items..

Comment: Is your caml query actually "some query goes here", or is that merely a placeholder to hide the actual query?

Comment: @wjervis It has some query to fetch data from related list. Also I've checked the Query with Query Builder & its fine..

Answer (score 0):

According to the comment of **OP**, It seems `SP.SOD.executeFunc` is missing. So it should be

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
    var hostsuburl = "Subsite URL goes here";
    var context = new SP.ClientContext(hostsuburl);
    var oList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("ResourceDetails");
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='monthnumber'/><Value Type='Text'>" + CurrentMonth + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    context.load(collListItem, 'Include(ActualHours,AvailableHours,CostPerHour)');
    context.executeQueryAsync(function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
        alert('Inside OnQuery succeeded');
    }, function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Error onQuery Failed');
    });
});
```

Comment: I've tried it. Now I can see alert from OnQueryFailed function.

Comment: That mean you have problem in your code. Let me know the error like `alert(args.get_message());` in  `OnQueryFailed`. Your problem is solved that you were unable to get into either onQuerySucceeded function & onQueryFailed

Comment: I'm getting Error:Unexpected response data from server error

Comment: That means you dont have permission in site you are accessing

Comment: Thanks for your effort, But I'm still not clear that what kind of error is it. I can use the same code to get the lists from root site itself. But I can't get into any subsite contents. Also I'm administrator & In app level, I've provided permission on AppManifest too.

Comment: Can you check your CAML queries also? You can ask another question also regarding current error. The problem you have mentioned is solved by my answer.

Comment: I've checked CAML Query with Query Designer, No error on CAML Query. Anyhow Thank you for your help..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34652/discussion-between-arun-and-atish-dipongkor).

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to access a list that is not on the app web, you must use the [cross domain library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  Here is an example of getting a Web object using JSOM:

```
var crossDomainRequest = function() {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
    var factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appweburl);
    context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
    var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, siteUrl);
    var web = appContextSite.get_web();
    context.load(web);
    context.executeQueryAsync(success, error);
};
```

- `appweburl` is the url for the app that is installed.
- `hostUrl` is the url for the web that the app is installed on.
- `siteUrl` is the url of the web you want to access.

Example, you install your app at `https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/somesite`.  That url will be the `hostUrl`.  Your `appweburl` will be `https://mytenant-61a62e04fdcd25.sharepoint.com/sites/somesite/myapp/`.  The hex string is inserted by SharePoint and is random.  If you want to access a list on `https://bhets.sharepoint.com/sites/somesite/subsite`, then set `siteUrl` to its url.

You will need to reference `SP.RequestExecutor.js` in order to execute the function:

```
var scriptbase = hostUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
$.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js", function() {
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function () {
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", crossDomainRequest);
    });
});
```

Comment: As I'm new to this, I've confusion that what is AppWeb & HostWeb. Could you pls explain?

Comment: I've Site Collection and several subsites (/RootSite, /RootSite/SubSite1, /RootSite/SubSite2). I'm creating this app to calculate some item values from subsites list and store it into list on root site. So I've to deploy this app part on Root Site only.

Comment: @Arun see my update

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Consider HostURL is `https://testsite.sharepoint.com/sites/root` and apparently appwebURL like `https://testsite-61a62e04fdcd25.sharepoint.com/sites/root`    I want to read list from `https://testsite.sharepoint.com/sites/root /subsite1`

Comment: Then use the url, `https://testsite.sharepoint.com/sites/root/subsite1/`, in place of `siteUrl`.

Comment: I can get into subsites now, but I'm not able to read list items. Could you pls let me know the correct way?

Comment: Does your app have read permission on site collection? If the site collection is different from the one the app is installed on, you'll need to do tenant isntead of site collection.

Comment: The app is in same site collection. The App loaded into Site Collection Root Site & have o read list from all subsites of that root site.